# Importing React using Webpack and JSX isn't recognised

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs

I'm a little baffled because my class has assigned three separate guides for React and they all do things differently. It has not been made clear to me which elements of what we are doing are Webpack, which are ES6, and which are Node, so forgive me if I describe things terribly.

I have the following `package.json`, skipping the unnecessary fields:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "^0.14.7",
        "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
        "webpack": "^1.12.13"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.4.5",
        "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
        "jshint": "^2.9.1",
        "jshint-loader": "^0.8.3",
        "node-libs-browser": "^1.0.0"
    }
}
```

I run `npm install`.

Now I have this Webpack config:

```
"use strict";
let webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: ["./main.es6"],
    output: {
        filename: "compiled.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.es6$/g,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.es6']
    },
    watch: true
};
```

Which as I understand it simply runs `main.es6` and any files it requires/references/imports from through the Babel loader. I do have a `.babelrc` file set up and I can confirm that it does work (transpiles things like arrow functions, classes, etc to ES5).

Now here's the tricky part. My page will be a table of lottery drawings; my React component is a row that gets passed an array of six numbers and appends it to an existing table.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const Drawing = props => (
 <tr>
     {props.numbers.map(n => <td>{n}</td>)}
 </tr>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Drawing />, document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0]);
```

This gets me a SyntaxError exception at the moment where `<tr>` is written. This kind of throws me, because in my mind if the React import succeeds (which it apparently does) then the JSX should be understood. The 'arrow function of `props`' style is apparently a bit unusual, but (a) the `class Drawing extends React.Component` form has the same issue and (b) it's being drilled into me that this stateless/functional style is nicer to work with now, and I can see the upsides of that.

I apologise for making a long post full of code samples, but I don't know what's important here and what's not. I can't work out how to correctly Google this issue and I can't really follow the logic in my head because I just get stuck on "Well, React imports, so... why would JSX not work?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line to your .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": ["react"]
}
```

It'is needed for transforming JSX syntax into native JavaScript. And if you haven't installed babel react preset yet, run `npm install babel-preset-react`.

> React import succeeds (which it apparently does) then the JSX should be understood.

React is not used for transforming JSX syntax, it is done entirely by Babel Syntax JSX plugin. And React don't use JSX in it's library files, so import was successful.

Comment: Thank you for this, it totally didn't occur to me that it'd be *Babel* parsing the JSX. I understand things better now, appreciate it.